# Netsuite Credit Memo odbc query returns extra line items

Tags: odbc, netsuite

For credit memo line items I am reading data from transaction_lines table.
But it returns extra lines than the actual ones.

For My credit memo I have one inventory line item and one other charges line.
But result shows.

1. Inventory line - `I need this`
2. Other charges Line - `I need this`
3. Inventory Asset Line - `I want to skip this`
4. Accounts Receivable Line - `I want to skip this`
5. Cost of Goods Sold Line - `I want to skip this`

Here is the query

```
select TRANSACTION_LINES.* 
from TRANSACTION_LINES
JOIN TRANSACTIONS on TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_ID = TRANSACTION_LINES.TRANSACTION_ID
where TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_ID = 11111
and TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'Credit Memo'
```

And in Netsuite there is an option to remove COGS,SHIPPING,TAX and MAIN Line.

I wanted to know how can I remove such lines by using odbc query.
Can you please help me with the query modifications.

Thank You,